# How To Avoid a Perl script calling an Another Perl Script

Tags: perl

i am calling a perl script client.pl from a main script to capture the output of client.pl 
in @output.

is there anyway to avoid the use of these two files so i can use the output of client.pl in main.pl itself

here is my code....

```
main.pl
=======

my @output = readpipe("client.pl");

client.pl
=========

#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#use strict;
use Socket;

#initialize host and port


my $host = shift || $FTP_SERVER;


my $port = shift || $CLIENT_PORT;

my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');

#get the port address
my $iaddr = inet_aton($host);
my $paddr = sockaddr_in($port, $iaddr);

#create the socket, connect to the port
socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)or die "socket: $!\n";
connect(SOCKET, $paddr) or die "connect: $!\n";

my $line;
while ($line = <SOCKET>)
{
    print "$line\n";
}
close SOCKET or die "close: $!";
```

/rocky..

Comment: @Rocky: note how "#" made some of your lines into headers rather than comments. Click on the orange question mark on the right site of the post writing toolbar or information on formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Put the common code in a package. [Use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) the package in client.pl and main.pl. Chapter 10 of [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271) has more information.

Comment: for packages, he first needs to use subroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are really trying to do, but might worh investigating a package such as Net::FTP ( http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3AFTP )

Answer (score 0):

you can do two things:

1. Merge the codes in client.pl and main.pl as your main function does no work other than printing. In case you want to do more from the incoming input data, you should do that in client.pl itself, coz an in-memory array(`@output`) may run out of RAM while reading large size data across the network.
2. If you want the output in an array (`@output`)

```
    sub client {
     # intialize ..
     my @array =  (); #empty array
     while ($line = <SOCKET>)
     {
      push(@array,$line);
     }
     return @array;
    }

   @output = client();

   print @output;
```

Other way, you can also use references:

```
    sub client {
     # intialize ..

     my @array =  (); #empty array
     while ($line = <SOCKET>)
     {
      push(@array,$line);
     }
     return @array;
    }

   my $output_ref = client();

   print @$output_ref; // dereference and print.
```